# The euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ is orientable as a manifold.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I know that

The euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ is orientable as a manifold.

---

I think that it is orientable because it has a nowhere vanishing $n$-form.

But I am not sure.

Please can you explain me more formally and mathematically?

Thank you:)

Comment: Do you know what "orientable" means?

Comment: Yes I know of course. @ChrisEagle I have explained why this is orienatable. But I wan to learn its reason more widely and more formally.

Comment: Is the reason I said enough to prove ? @ChrisEagle

Answer (score 3):

One very simple way of doing this is showing that

> If a manifold has an atlas with exactly *one* chart, then it is orientable.

Of course, this applies to euclidean spaces.

Comment: Well, how can I show the existence of an atlas with exactly one chart for $\Bbb R^n$ ? Please can you explain more?

Comment: Bu the way thank you for help. :)

Comment: If $\phi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is the identity map, then the set $\{\phi\}$ is an atlas for $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I have one more question to you. Well, I think that it has a nowhere vanishing n-form. So it is orienatable. How can I show this?

Comment: I never hear What you said from my teacher. So I am confused. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a natural set of global coordinates. Use these to write down a pointwise basis for $\Lambda^1_x(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now use those to write down a basis for $\Lambda^n_x(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The coordinates are global. What does that tell you about your basis of $\Lambda^n_x(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: The basis are Nowhere vanishing ?